# Call specific arrays in csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I want to display 1st and 2nd arrays only in each row from file output.csv like this:

```
[0]     [1]       [2]         [3]
2   111.72501   0.125     10.440862
2   111.77499   7.50E-02  10.565194
2   111.77499   0.125     10.903052
2   111.77499   0.175     10.461977
2   111.82501   2.50E-02  10.142186
```

with this script:

```
$lines = file('output.csv');
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
echo 'x='.$line[1].',y='.$line[2]. '<br />';
```

instead it only displays ',' and '1' as a result. Any suggestion?

Comment: `file()` doesn't parse it as a CSV file. It just returns each line as a string.

Comment: What's the delimiter between columns in the file? Is it a TAB character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strgetcsv()` to parse each line as CSV, then show the fields you want.

```
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $cols = str_getcsv($line);
    echo 'x='.$cols[1].',y='.$cols[2]. '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Why isn't there a comma in the file you showed in the question?

Comment: I'm not sure. It was converted from text file which is 'tab' delimited. I was doing trial and error, actually.